# Why are the coins in the sewers of Super Mario Sunshine question marks?

Tags: super-mario-sunshine

Is there any particular reason why the coins in the sewers of Super Mario Sunshine are questions marks instead of coin icons? Is it a glitch, or is their significance to it? Maybe (a lame) gameplay reason to keep you guessing what's underground?

[Here's a video of what I mean](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=GuHzQL_aEHI#t=28s)

Comment: Well, it's dark under there!  You can't see them.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't specific to coins - any items in the sewers that you can't see are question marks, and you'll have to judge by the sound (among other things) to determine what you pick up.

Coins are by far the most common, but you can also run into 1-UP mushrooms.

Comment: Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Jeff Hard to know. If I had to guess, it'd be because the silhouette of a coin isn't obvious as such due to the angle and the lack of a discrete cutaway (Mario's a silhouette also).

Comment: Was there not silhouette's in Super Mario Galaxy? (I can't remember at all actually, but I don't remember question marks standing out like they do in SMS)

Comment: @Jeff Yes (IIRC), but SMG offers many more opportunities for the camera to not be able to see items, from what I've seen of both games.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the camera can't see them. Simple as that. They added this so you can still see what is going on.

Answer (score -2):

The game's camera replaces all entities in your field of view that are blocked another object with a gray question mark. not replacing this in the sewer was either an oversight by the developers, or more likely, their way to keep the game from glitching out when figuring out if an object was in the sewers or not.